# Proving that stopped Brownian motions has a limit.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, weak-convergence

Assume that $(\tau_n)$,$(T_n)$ are finite strictly increasing stopping times and set $\tau=\sup_{n}\tau_n$,$T=\sup_{n}T_n$. Now consider a process $(W_t)_{t<\tau}$, and a Brownian motion $B$,
which satisfies that $(W^{\tau_n},\tau_n)\stackrel{D}{=}(B^{T_n},T_n)$ . Moreover, assume that $(W^{\tau_n},\tau_n)\stackrel{wk}{\rightarrow}(B^{T},T)$. I claim that:

***$W$ has left limit at $\tau$, and defining $W_\tau:=W_{\tau^-}$ gives that $W^\tau\sim B^T$.***

Can anybody verify if my claim is true? If so, a proof or a reference would be appreciated. I feel like i have tried every trick in the book, but i have a hard time adapting the ideas to the case where $W$ is not defined on the entire $[0,\infty)$ interval.

Comment: @Shalop. By $B^{T_n}$ I think that he means the stopped process defined as $B^{T_n}_t=B_{t \land T_n}$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $W$ has continuous sample paths on $[0,\tau)$, and that $\Bbb P(\tau<\infty)=1$.

The process $\exp(B_t-t/2)$ is a positive martingale; consequently $X_t:=\exp(B_t-t/2)1_{\{t<T\}}$ is a non-negative supermartingale.
It is clear from the hypotheses that the process $X$ has the same finite-dimensional distributions as the process $Y_t:=\exp(W_t-t/2)1_{\{t<\tau\}}$, which is therefore also a supermartingale. Moreover, the process $Y$ is right-continuous on $[0,\infty)$. But a right-continuous supermartingale possesses left limits on $(0,\infty)$ almost surely. 
It follows that the left limit $Y_{\tau-}=\lim_{t\uparrow \tau}Y_t$ exists almost surely, and $\Bbb P(Y_{\tau-}>0)=\Bbb P(X_{T-}>0)=1$.
Consequently $W_{\tau-}=\lim_{t\uparrow \tau}[\log(Y_t)+t/2]=\log(Y_{\tau-})+\tau/2$ exists, almost surely. 
 The rest is clear sailing.

Comment: Lovely. I have not seen your new answer till now. I must admit that i did not have the prerequisites to understanding your previous answer. Meanwhile i found a solution very similar to yours. I proved that $\exp(B_t)$ is a supermartingale per definition.

I don't feel like the extra assumption about $\tau$ being a.s. finite is needed. I guess you can conclude that $(\tau<\infty)\subset (Y_{\tau^-}  \text{exists and} >0)$. Then you take log and apply the remaining clear sailing?

Comment: Yes, the finiteness of $\tau$ was just for convenience.

Comment: Why is it that $X_t$ and $Y_t$ have the same finite-dimensional distributions? I can see that this would be true if $T$ and $\tau$ were replaced with $T_n$ and $\tau_n$ respectively, but in the limit it is not immediately clear to me...

Comment: Not sure either, but as i wrote i proved that it was a supermartingale per definition of a supermartingale, using monotone convergence for conditional expectations, since $Y_t$ is the pointwise limit of $1_{(t\leq T_n)}(t)\exp(W_t^{\tau_n}-(t\wedge \tau_n)/2)$

Comment: Yep, that works.